# "Cannot resolve symbol" on all of the MultiLayerNetwork's methods

Tags: java, machine-learning, intellij-idea, neural-network, deeplearning4j

Here's a [link](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/getting-started/tutorials/quickstart-with-mnist) to the tutorial I'm following.

I'm using IntelliJ, Maven is installed correctly, initally I was using JDK 13.0.2 but switched to JDK 1.8.0_261 to try and fix this error. Here's the code so far:

```
package org.deeplearning4j.examples;

import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.BaseDatasetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.EmnistDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.DenseLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.OutputLayer;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.WeightInit;
import org.nd4j.linalg.activations.Activation;
import org.nd4j.linalg.learning.config.Adam;
import org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions;

import java.io.IOException;

public class learnNum {
    int batchSize = 128; // how many examples to simultaneously train in the network
    EmnistDataSetIterator.Set emnistSet = EmnistDataSetIterator.Set.BALANCED;
    EmnistDataSetIterator emnistTrain;
    { try { emnistTrain = new EmnistDataSetIterator(emnistSet, batchSize, true); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }
    EmnistDataSetIterator emnistTest;
    { try { emnistTest = new EmnistDataSetIterator(emnistSet, batchSize, false); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }

    int outputNum = EmnistDataSetIterator.numLabels(emnistSet); // total output classes
    int rngSeed = 123; // integer for reproducability of a random number generator
    int numRows = 28; // number of "pixel rows" in an mnist digit
    int numColumns = 28;

    MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
        .seed(rngSeed)
        .updater(new Adam())
        .l2(1e-4)
        .list()
        .layer(new DenseLayer.Builder()
            .nIn(numRows * numColumns) // Number of input datapoints.
            .nOut(1000) // Number of output datapoints.
            .activation(Activation.RELU) // Activation function.
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER) // Weight initialization.
            .build())
        .layer(new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
            .nIn(1000)
            .nOut(outputNum)
            .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .build())
        .build();
    MultiLayerNetwork network = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
    network.init();

    // pass a training listener that reports score every 10 iterations
    int eachIterations = 10;
    network.addListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(eachIterations));
    int numEpochs = 2;
    network.fit(emnistTrain, numEpochs);


}
```

Everything seems to be "compiling" correctly (I'm not sure that's the correct term) in IntelliJ except for all of the methods called on the MultiLayerNetwork "network". So for example, network.init(), the "init()" is red and in the errors it says "Cannot resolve symbol". Same for addListeners and fit(). I don't think it's an import problem since intelliJ would handle that and I already imported the MultiLayerNetwork. I even reset my laptop incase it was some corruption causing it but it didn't fix the issue. So if anyone can provide any help I'd be thankful.

Edit: I was asked to add the XML file so here it is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ~ Copyright (c) 2020 Konduit K.K.
  ~ Copyright (c) 2015-2019 Skymind, Inc.
  ~
  ~ This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
  ~ terms of the Apache License, Version 2.0 which is available at
  ~ https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  ~ WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
  ~ License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
  ~ under the License.
  ~
  ~ SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>                                       
    <artifactId>dl4j-examples</artifactId>                         
    <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>                                              
    <name>Introduction to DL4J</name>                                     
    <description>A set of examples introducing the DL4J framework</description>   

    <properties>
        <dl4j-master.version>1.0.0-beta7</dl4j-master.version>
        <!-- Change the nd4j.backend property to nd4j-cuda-X-platform to use CUDA GPUs -->
        <!-- <nd4j.backend>nd4j-cuda-10.2-platform</nd4j.backend> -->           
        <nd4j.backend>nd4j-native</nd4j.backend>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.minimum.version>3.3.1</maven.minimum.version>
        <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.4.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
        <jcommon.version>1.0.23</jcommon.version>
        <jfreechart.version>1.0.13</jfreechart.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.29</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.48.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
                                                                                
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>${nd4j.backend}</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-api</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-data-image</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-local</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-datasets</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-zoo</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ParallelWrapper & ParallelInference live here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-parallel-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used in the feedforward/classification/MLP* and feedforward/regression/RegressionMathFunctions example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>${jfreechart.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>${jcommon.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for downloading data in some of the examples -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-data-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- Maven Enforcer: Ensures user has an up to date version of Maven before building -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>                                                            
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>                  
                <version>1.0.1</version>                                        
                <executions>                                                    
                    <execution>                                                 
                        <id>enforce-default</id>                                
                        <goals>                                                 
                            <goal>enforce</goal>                                
                        </goals>                                                
                        <configuration>                                         
                            <rules>                                             
                                <requireMavenVersion>                           
                                    <version>[${maven.minimum.version},)</version>
                                    <message>********** Minimum Maven Version is ${maven.minimum.version}. Please upgrade Maven before continuing (run "mvn --version" to check). **********</message>
                                </requireMavenVersion>                          
                            </rules>                                            
                        </configuration>                                        
                    </execution>                                                
                </executions>                                                   
            </plugin>  
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>                                                            
                <groupId>com.lewisd</groupId>                                   
                <artifactId>lint-maven-plugin</artifactId>                      
                <version>0.0.11</version>                                       
                <configuration>                                                 
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>                     
                    <onlyRunRules>                                              
                        <rule>DuplicateDep</rule>                               
                        <rule>RedundantPluginVersion</rule>                     
                        <!-- Rules incompatible with Java 9                     
                        <rule>VersionProp</rule>                                
                        <rule>DotVersionProperty</rule> -->                     
                    </onlyRunRules>                                             
                </configuration>                                                
                <executions>                                                    
                    <execution>                                                 
                        <id>pom-lint</id>                                       
                        <phase>validate</phase>                                 
                        <goals>                                                 
                            <goal>check</goal>                                  
                        </goals>                                                
                    </execution>                                                
                </executions>                                                   
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>${shadedClassifier}</shadedClassifierName>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/datanucleus/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>                                                      
            <plugins>                                                           
                <plugin>                                                        
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>                          
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>                  
                    <version>1.0.0</version>                                    
                    <configuration>                                             
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>                              
                            <pluginExecutions>                                  
                                <pluginExecution>                               
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>                     
                                        <groupId>com.lewisd</groupId>           
                                        <artifactId>lint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[0.0.11,)</versionRange>  
                                        <goals>                                 
                                            <goal>check</goal>                  
                                        </goals>                                
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>                    
                                    <action>                                    
                                        <ignore/>                               
                                    </action>                                   
                                </pluginExecution>                              
                            </pluginExecutions>                                 
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>                             
                    </configuration>                                            
                </plugin>                                                       
            </plugins>                                                          
        </pluginManagement>   
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using maven to compile your project? If that's the case, could you post your `pom.xml` file with your question?

Comment: @Patrick hey, I just added it. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do you see library containing "org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer" in "Project Structure | Modules - Dependencies"?

Comment: @y.bedrov no I don't see it. What should I do?

Comment: Please try to run "Reimport" from Maven tool window.